# Swift string interpolation performance

Tags: ios, swift, performance

I have a lot of `print()` statements throughout my iOS/Swift project. I've written a global override as follows so that these get ignored in release builds:

```
func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items, separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
    #endif
}
```

When calling `print()` I sometimes pass in objects with expensive custom `debugDescription` properties, for example:

```
print("Value of myArray: \(myArray)")
```

with `myArray` implementing a custom `debugDescription` like so:

```
var debugDescription: String {
    get {
        // Serialise the array for printing
    }
}
```

My question is, will the `debugDescription` value get computed before passing the string to `print()` or after? I.e. will the `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive eliminate the computation from release builds?

EDIT: I'm aware `debugDescription` is a computed property, I'm just not sure when it's called. I'm not calling it myself; it's called automatically as part of the string interpolation. So if Swift interpolates the string before passing it into `print()`, it still computes the property. But if Swift saves the "instruction" instead and only evaluates the string in the inner built-in `Swift.print()` function, then I get a performance gain. 
Hence this question is really about how Swift handles string interpolation with regards to performance.

Comment: Since `debugDescription` is a computed property, it will be generated every time you call `debugDescription`. But this whole thing sounds like micro-optimization to me

Comment: What do you mean by micro-optimisation?

Comment: In most situations, it takes milliseconds to generate that string. There are cases when milliseconds matter. Worry about performance then

Comment: I call `print()` a lot, frequently inside loops, and frequently with long arrays. I don't want to iterate through all that if I don't have to.

Comment: You should seriously look into using a proper logging framework. I would recommend the [built-in logging facilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) provided by macOS/iOS, as they are very well tuned for performance. For one, strings are passed as `@autoclosure`, so they're only evaluated when necessary (e.g. debug log statements are ignored in release builds)

Comment: Ooh, reading about autoclosures has pretty much answered all my questions. Thankyou!

Comment: I'd also refer you to the WWDC 2016 [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will the `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive eliminate the computation from release builds?

No, it won't. Swift evaluates all function arguments the moment a function is called. You can verify this either in the debugger or by adding a call to `Swift.print` to your `debugDescription` implementation. For example, create a file with these contents:

```
// test.swift
struct A: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    let value: Int

    var debugDescription: String {
        Swift.print("Calling debugDescription")
        return "A: \(value)"
    }
}

func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items, separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
    #endif
}

let a = A(value: 42)
print("Value of a: \(a)")
```

Then, in Terminal:

```
> swift test.swift
Calling debugDescription
```

As you can see, `"Calling debugDescription"` gets printed (i.e., `debugDescription` gets evaluated) even though your `print` function doesn't do anything. Now let's set the `DEBUG` flag:

```
> swift -D DEBUG test.swift
Calling debugDescription
["Value of a: A: 42"]
```

This is why similar functions in the Swift standard library (such as `assert`) use [autoclosures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID543) for one or more of their parameters. The `@autoclosure` attribute wraps a function argument in a closure. This way, the function being called can decide if and when to evaluate the expression (by calling the function). This is fully transparent to the caller.

Unfortunately, `@autoclosure` does not work with variadic parameters (like `Any...`), so I don't think there's a way to reproduce what you want exactly in Swift 4.0. However, if you can live with a `print` function that takes a single `Any` argument, you can define your function like this:

```
func print(_ item: @autoclosure () -> Any, separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(item(), separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
    #endif
}
```

Now, the function will not evaluate its first argument until you call `item()`, which only happens inside the `#if DEBUG` block, so there's no overhead in release builds.

Answer (score -1):

Preprocessing will not include code inside #if DEBUG into release code. So, since it’s computed property, don’t worrry, no effect on release code optimization